# Does a Higgs Boson propagate in space?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

Since a Boson my first guess is that it can propagate through space however because its zero elementary spin compared to the spin 1 of other Bosons I guess it has not helicity. Does this mean that for its short lifetime the Higgs remains immovable in space during the time of its detection?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you think spin is connected to the ability of a particle to propagate?

Comment: The helicity is the projection of the spin onto the direction of motion. Zero spin just means zero helicity. But why would this mean the particle cannot move?

Comment: I am interested in ways if possible, to accelerate Higgs particles. I don't think a spin zero particle can translate in space and not being changed to another particle(s).

Comment: @Markoul11  the numbers here will enlighten you https://cms.cern/news/life-higgs-boson

Comment: @Markoul11 alpha particles (and helium atoms), are scalar. Neither define an absolute rest frame by not propagating in space.

Comment: He-4  is spin 0 charge zero and effectively appear as a scalar particle but is still combinatoric when integrated in time.

Comment: for 1.6E-22 s even at close the speed of light it will translate ~0.048 pm. I don't believe an elementary scalar particle can ever translate in space. It is space.

Comment: Only in its Rest frame....

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean to "propagate in space"? The Higgs is a scalar boson (and field), so all inertial frames see the exact same Higgs field, and the boson has a four momentum $p_{\mu}$. There's always a frame where $p_{\mu}=0$, so it is always not propagating in 1 set of frames, and propagating in many more.

Answer (score 1):

The pi0 has zero spin and the [particle data group](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-tab-mesons-light.pdf) has the links to the measurements of its lifetime. If it has a lifetime, it also has a probability to travel a distance, same as the charged pions, except the probability that it can be measured in a detector would be very small, as it decays fast. (charged pions decay by the weak interaction so [can be seen in the lab](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-liquid-hydrogen-bubble-chamber-photograph-of-a-negatively-charged-136530391.html))

The same argument  is true for the standard model [higgs boson.](https://cms.cern/news/life-higgs-boson)